# View Scaffolding for Second foreign key isn't correct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm creating a simple 3 model MVC 5.2.3 example in Visual Studio with Entity framework version 6.1.3.

I have a `Vehicle` which has a 1 to many relationship with `Contract` and `Mileage` has a 1 to many relationship with `Contract` also.

`Contract` has 2 foreign keys, one for `Vehicle` and one for `Mileage`. I've added some data annotations to specify keys and foreign keys which according to what I've read should be unnecessary as I've stuck to the expected naming convention.

In the `Contract` view the first foreign key which is `Vehicle` has a populated dropdown with the actual vehicles in it, which is correct. The problem is the second foreign key, the `Mileage`, has a dropdown loaded with the `Mileage` IDs and not the actual mileages.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Code below.

Razor view:

```
@model RRSMVCTest5.Models.Contract

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Contract</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VehicleId, "VehicleId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("VehicleId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VehicleId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MileageId, "MileageId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("MileageId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MileageId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InitialPayment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InitialPayment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InitialPayment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MonthlyPayment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MonthlyPayment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MonthlyPayment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

View models:

```
public class Contract
{
    //[Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VehicleId")]
    virtual public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }        
    public int MileageId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MileageId")]
    virtual public Mileage Mileage { get; set;}

    public double InitialPayment { get; set; }
    public double MonthlyPayment { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    {
        Contracts = new List<Contract>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }               
}

public class Mileage
{
    public Mileage()
    {
        Contracts=new List<Contract>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int MileageId { get; set; }
    public int AnnualMileage { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}
```

Curiously when I change the data type of 'AnnualMileage' from int to string the 
dropdown gets loaded with the 'AnnualMileage' property as required. Does any one know of any annotation that can be used in the model to express which field should be chosen for display? A decision is being made by the scaffolding generator that would be useful to have control over.

Comment: Could you attach the razor view?

Comment: @Rich Why did you break it again? Please don't touch it for a while.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy think we were editing it at the same time. I'd added the wrong razor view so I replaced it before I'd seen you'd fixed it. Apologies.

Comment: OK, I reformatted it again. There is a single very simple rule to format text as the code block - indent it by 4 spaces. That's all.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `Vehicle` model contains the `Name` property, but the `Mileage` doesn't, so the Razor helper `DropDownList` doesn't know what should be displayed as a text in the case of the `Mileage` and displays the IDs instead.

So you have two possibilities:

- add the `Name` property to the `Mileage` model
- tell the `DropDownList` helper what property to use for dropdown's text

I would choose the second option:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropDownId", Model.Select(item => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = item.MileageId.ToString(),
    Text = item.AnnualMileage.ToString()
}))
```

Comment: That did occur to me just after I posted the question so I changed the AnnualMileage field to Name as a test, deleted the controllers and views and regenerated them but the problem remained. RE your second suggestion, I'm trying to learn how to generate correct scaffolding , so don't really want to give that up and edit issues manually just yet

Comment: I don't think changing the model according to view's needs is a good way. You should be doing the opposite - change the view according to model. So tell the `DropDownList` what property it should use for the displayed text. Anyway, it should be named `Text`, not `Name` (but that doesn't explain why it works in the case of `Vehicle`).

Comment: I only made the name change as a test. I'm now researching along the lines of an attribute that I can apply to the property to tell the code generator to use this in a dropdown. The [Display] attribute looks promising so I'll try that next and report back. I've retested having changed the property to "Text" but the problem persists.